# SQL Server 2016 How to read/write to an always encrypted column from command line?

Tags: c#, command-line, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I am able to read and write to a column with always encrypted from a C# ASP.NET app. However, I need to do it from sqlcmd.

After some research I found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility), that you need the -g parameter to activate the Column Encryption Setting, and to update to sqlcmd version 13.1, which I did and verified with "sqlcmd -?".

So, I made a test table:

```
create table tmp 
(
tmp_id int identity(1,1) not null,
test varchar(500)
COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2
ENCRYPTED WITH 
   (ENCRYPTION_TYPE = RANDOMIZED, 
    ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', 
    COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = MY_Encryption_Key)  
null
);
```

And made a test.sql with the following:

```
insert into tmp (test) values ('mytest');
```

I call sqlcmd like this:

```
sqlcmd.exe -g -b -S "localhost\SQL2016" -d "my_db_name" -i "D:\test.sql" -U "my_username" -P "my_password"
```

But I get the following error, whether I use "-g" or not:

```
Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(8000) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'MY_Encryption_Key', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'my_db_name') collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
```

If I change test.sql to:

```
declare @test varchar(8000) = 'mytest';
insert into tmp (test) values (@test);
```

Then I get another error (still with or without -g):

```
Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables '@test'. The encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'PLAINTEXT') and the expression near line '2' expects it to be (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'MY_Encryption_Key', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'my_db_name') (or weaker).
```

I need this because currently there is a C# app that accepts a flat file, and then it is loaded into the DB through command line by calling ".sql" files. Now some columns need to be encrypted. So, we need sqlcmd to read/write the encrypted columns to avoid rewriting all the logic in C#.NET.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this even possible? Why is the "-g" parameter of sqlcmd not making a difference?

Comment: Try casting the value as varchar(8000) when you insert.

Comment: It did not work, I had already tried

Comment: If this worked, you would have effectively *circumvented* the Always Encrypted feature, given that the strings in your .sql files are *not encrypted*. The `-g` option allows `sqlcmd` to retrieve data from AE columns (if it has access to the keys), but it still cannot run arbitrary T-SQL using unencrypted values, no more than other clients could. The values must be properly parameterized from a client that supports it. That means plaintext T-SQL scripts are out. SSMS has some hacky support for that now since it *is* a pain in the ass, but `sqlcmd` is not sophisticated enough.

Answer (score 2):

Currently inserting data into an always encrypted column using the following syntax is **only supported in SSMS**.

```
declare @test varchar(8000) = 'mytest';
insert into tmp (test) values (@test);
```

You can find details regarding this [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/12/13/parameterization-for-always-encrypted-using-ssms-to-insert-into-update-and-filter-by-encrypted-columns/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-using-sql-server-management-studio)

Answer (score 1):

create table tmp
 
(

tmp_id int identity(1,1) not null,

test nvarchar(11)

COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2

ENCRYPTED WITH 

   (ENCRYPTION_TYPE = RANDOMIZED, 

    ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',

    COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = CEK_Auto1)
null

);

Create procedure [dbo].[Proc_Test]

    @test nvarchar(11)

AS

insert into tmp (test) values (@test);

above code is worked for me in SSMS.

Comment: Your code creates a table and creates a stored procedure, but doesn't _call_ the stored procedure.  Using it on my end, I get `Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with nvarchar(11) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'tkcMuckAround')`